# Geckodriver not opening after running generated python code by Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, ide

Geckodriver is not opening after running python code. This code is generated by Selenium IDE itself but I have modified it since it will have errors whenever I run it.

```
# Generated by Selenium IDE
#import pytest
#import time
#import json
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

class TestJune17():
  def setup_method(self, method):
    self.driver = webdriver.Firefox()
#    self.vars = {}

#  def teardown_method(self, method):
#    self.driver.quit();

  def test_june17(self):
    self.driver.get("****")
    self.driver.set_window_size(1008, 699)
    self.driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".login-password").send_keys("****")
    self.driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".login-username").send_keys("*****")
    self.driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "button").click()
    self.driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".add").click()
    self.driver.find_element(By.LINK_TEXT, "User Defined").click()
    self.driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".library-item:nth-child(3) > .title").click()
    self.driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".form-group:nth-child(1) .required").click()
    self.driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".form-group:nth-child(1) .required").send_keys("*******")
    self.driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".form-group:nth-child(6) .editor-input").click()
    self.driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".form-group:nth-child(6) .editor-input").send_keys("*****")
    self.driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".bold li:nth-child(3)").click()
    self.driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".editor-toggle-switch > .toggle").click()
    self.driver.find_element(By.ID, "select2-cm8h-container").click()
    self.driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".small").click()
    self.driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".small").send_keys("****")
    self.driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".editor-view-group > .form-group .editor-input").click()
    self.driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".editor-view-group > .form-group .editor-input").send_keys("***")
    self.driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".primary-action").click()
```

Comment: Is it a full script? If answer is "yes", you have to call your method `setup_method(self, method)` from class TestJune17().

Answer (score 0):

You should set path to geckodriver on your PC.

```
self.driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path="path/to/geckodriver")
```